# Pseudocode dice algorithm, need some guidance

Tags: javascript, pseudocode

> In this exercise, you will roll a pair of dice until the numbers add up to a given number. You can assume that the given number is 2, 3, 6, or 12. Using pseudocode, write an algorithm that returns the number of times the dice is rolled to achieve this number.

I have absolutely no idea how to start doing this. Can you guide me a bit?

Also what does the last sentence mean?

Comment: No one is going to write your code for you - start with something - then show your attempt - you'll get a lot more help by showing an effort

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started.  The detail the assignment calls for is likely one or two levels refined from here.  For example, what does "roll a die" mean.  Probably something to do with saving a random number of some sort to a variable....

```
define rollRequiredForA(target) {
    if target is not an integer or is outside the valid bounds abort

    initialize a counter to 0

    loop
        increase the counter by one
        roll two dice
        add results together
        if the result equals target return counter
    end loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First let me address your question about the last sentence of the problem:

I'll break it down in parts.

First pseudocode is a simplification of the steps that you would need to take in solving a problem in a format that is very representative of code but is not actual code written in any programming language. For example pseudocode could be something like this:

```
if the earlier result is 2 then
   use this list: Britney, Caitie, Sierrah
else
   use this other list: Brooke, Josh, Zach
```

Secondly an algorithm is a set of rules to followed in calculating or solving a problem. It's like a formula for solving a problem. Some everyday examples could be:

- **Driving home**: what route should you take? Will there be traffic on the shortest route? If so, will it slow you down more than taking a slightly longer route? These are all questions that would be asked in an algorithm.
- **Sorting**: Typically when you sort something, you do it in a specific way even though you may not realize it such as checking each one and pulling the first out of the pile and putting it on top and then the second and then the third and so on and so forth.
- **Dividing and conquering**: This is another very common algorithm in everyday life.

For more examples check out [this quora post](https://www.quora.com/Why-and-How-algorithms-are-important-in-our-daily-life)

So in other words, the last sentence is asking you to write a simplification of the steps that you would need to take to calculate the amount of rolls of the dice it takes to get those two dice to add up to the given number.

Now that that is out of the way, lets tackle the actual problem

To get you started, you'll have to run some sort of loop (maybe use a do-while loop?), and probably best to do it inside some sort of method. You'll need to have a counter if your dice don't add up to the target roll again and increase the counter until your roll adds up to the target, then return that value of the counter

```
define rolls needed(target)

   initialize counter as 0
   initialize sum

   do this loop
      increase your counter  
      roll your dice
      add results together
   while sum does not equal target

   return your counter
end
```

Comment: pcode is a great way to discover (and correct) flaws, like for example what would happen if your first roll of the dice (outside your while) hit the target? :-)

Comment: I'm sorry but that is very difficult to follow in a comment fjoo , add it to your question and i can update my answer. And good catch @JonSG thanks!